# Using react npm modules without webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to use for example `react-slider` module in website, where only few components are written in `React`.

When I was using `webpack` I sould do the following:

```
@import ReactSlider from 'react-slider';
```

but how can I use it in my components if I connect `react` and `react-dom` in `head` of my `html` and my connect my components with `script` tag?